# Appendix in LaTeX

Tags: table-of-contents, appendices, babel

I have the following document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}
 \usepackage[titletoc]{appendix}

 \begin{document}

  \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
  \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
  \tableofcontents

  \chapter{First chapter}

  \begin{appendices}
   \addappheadtotoc
   \appendixpage
   \clearpage
   \chapter{Some name}
   \label{label1}
   blah blah
  \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

this gives in the ToC:

```
Apéndice Appendices....................60
Apéndice A. Some name..................63
```

and in the body of the document:

```
Appendices
(page skip)
Apéndice A
Some name

blah blah
```

1. The TOC shows `"Apéndice Appendices"` and I need it to show `"Apéndices"` (note the "s" at the end of that word; it's **not** the same word that the first one currently in the TOC) Also in the body of the document it shows `"Appendices"` (in english) and I also need it to say `"Apéndices"` (in spanish), ie: the same word that should be displayed in the TOC. This looks like a `babel` issue to me.
2. Is there a way **not** to have to give each appendix a name? This is done with the `\chapter{Some name}` command, but I'd like the name of `Apéndice A` to be just that: `Apéndice A`. This way the ToC would look like (assuming the 1st point is fixed):

   ```
   Apéndices........................60
   Apéndice A.......................63
   ```

   and the body of the document:

   ```
   Apéndices
   (page skip)
   Apéndice A

   blah blah
   ```

   Is there any way to do this?

---

I think a hack to accomplish the 2nd point would be to combine @murray's answer with not giving a name to the chapter. This is, this line `\chapter{Some name}` would have to be replaced by:

```
\chapter[]{}
```

It's not pretty but I think it gets the job done.
If anybody knows of a more elegant way to do this, please let me know.

Comment: Please provide a bit more information about your document's setup: Which document class do you use, do you use the `babel` package (and, if so, which which language(s))?

Comment: Done @Mico, tell me if there's anything else I should add.

Comment: Done @Caramdir. It's **very** minimal, my actual set up is quite huge, but I think it's enough to give an idea.

Comment: @Gaba_p: That's exactly how it should be. (I can't help you personally but I'm sure with that info added someone else will be able to help you.)

Comment: The `Apéndice Appendices` in the TOC is not how it should be. The rest probably is, but I would like to change it either way. Thanks anyway, cheers.

Comment: @Gaba_p: No, I meant the MWE is exactly how it should be (i.e. very minimal).

Comment: For your second question: How do you want the actual page of the appendix be formatted? Just `\chapter{}` gives “Apéndice A” in a font slightly smaller than the normal chapter title and then a huge ugly space.

Comment: I want "Apéndice A" to be the **actual** name of the chapter, but I can't name it with `\chapter{Apéndice A}` because then I would get "Apéndice A" twice. I just don't think it's necessary to give a name to the appendix, "Apéndice A" (or "Appendix A" in english) should be enough.

Comment: @Gaba_p Since your second question is a separate issue (and will need a redefinition of (parts of) `\chapter`), I'd recommend asking a new question just about that problem.

Comment: @Caramdir will do as soon as I have some time today or perhaps tomorrow. Thank you so much for all your help. Regards.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I understand the `appendix` manual correctly, then the `\addappheadtotoc` and `\appendixpage` should only be used if the `appendices` environment is not used. If the `appendices` environment is used, then the same effect is created by using the `toc` and `page` package options, i.e. loading the package as

```
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
```

Further, since `babel` doesn't contain translations for the `appendix` package, you have to set them yourself:

```
\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Ap\'endices}
```

The actual appendices are then created with (note that the `\clearpage` is not needed)

```
\begin{appendices}
  \chapter{Some name}
  blah blah
\end{appendices}
```

This gives me the desired result:

[image: result]

Comment: Your answer **almost** takes care of the 1st issue. The only problem is that I'm still getting "Appendices" in english instead of "Apéndices" in spanish, which is what I actually need.

Comment: @Gaba_p: Sorry, I missed that. See the updated answer.

Comment: Thank you @Caramdir, your solution worked great for the 1st point.

Comment: Since I'll be moving the second part of this question onto its own question, I'll mark this as the answer for the 1st point.

Answer (score 2):

I think the following will do what you want: for each individual appendix, instead of `\chapter{Some name}` use `\chapter[]{Some name}`.

Comment: Your comment made me realize an error I had in the `MWE`. I've corrected it now: added `\label{label1}` below `\chapter{Some name}`. Now, I'm not sure what your answer is supposed to do, could you explain it a bit please?

Comment: I think I see now: your answer makes the "Some name" disappear from the TOC, but unfortunately it still needs the `\chapter{Some name}` command and it still shows that name in the document body. It also doesn't fix the 1st issue. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I used this answer in combination with an ugly hack to somehow fix the 2nd point. It's not a full answer so I can't mark it as such though. Regards.