# Not naming an appendix

Tags: appendices

Consider the following document:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
 \usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}
 \begin{document}

 \setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
 \setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
 \tableofcontents

 \chapter{First chapter}

 \begin{appendices}
  \chapter[]{Name of appendix}
  \label{ap1}
   blah blah
 \end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

This produces in the `TOC`:

```
Contents

1 First chapter......3
Appendices...........5
Appendix A...........7
```

and in the body of the document:

```
Chapter 1
First chapter

Appendices

Appendix A
Name of appendix
blah blah
```

I don't want to give a name to the appendix, I find it irrelevant. But I'm forced to do it with the `\chapter[]{Name of appendix}` command.

Is there a way **not** to have to give each appendix a name? This is the result I want in the body of the document (the `TOC` stays the same):

```
Chapter 1
First chapter

Appendices

Appendix A
blah blah
```

Now, I know I can just leave the `\chapter[]{}` command empty and so the title won't show, but I'm looking for a more integral solution and not just an ugly hack.

PD: this question originated [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/61488/appendix-in-latex).

---

**EDIT**

I'm sorry but I'd forgotten my document is in spanish so I didn't add the specific packages. This is what the document looks like now with Werner's new definitions added:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nonameappendix}{%
\def\@makechapterhead##1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@ % <--- Removed
      \fi
    \fi
    %\interlinepenalty\@M % <--- Removed
    %\Huge \bfseries ##1\par\nobreak % <--- Removed
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}%
\def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter%
          \fi
        \fi
        }}{}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\newappendix}{\chapter[]{}}%
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish,activeacute]{babel}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\renewcommand{\appendixtocname}{Ap\'endices}
\renewcommand{\appendixpagename}{Ap\'endices}
\begin{appendices}

  \nonameappendix
  \newappendix
  \label{ap1}
  \include{apendiceA}

\end{appendices}

\end{document}
```

where the `apendiceA.tex` file has nothing but text (ie: no chapter commands, no labels, etc..)

The issues I'm having with this is:

1-I get `Apéndice A.` in the TOC (notice the dot at the end). This is really minor but it still bugs me.

2- In the body of the document, after the `Apéndice A` title is displayed the text only begins in the next page. This is more serious.

Comment: @percusse The problem with `\chapter[]{}` is the formatting. It will display "Appendix A" in a font that is smaller than the usual title font and then there will be a big vertical space after it. Also, it will add "Appendix A." (with a dot at the end) to the ToC.

Comment: if you want to add stuff to the `toc` you can use the [`\addcontentsline`](http://insti.physics.sunysb.edu/latex-help/ltx-193.html) command

Comment: if there's only one appendix, forget about `appendices` and just use `\chapter*{Appendix}` along with `\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Appendix}` (with the correct spanish title, of course).

Comment: In the example there's only one appendix, but there can (will) be more.

Answer (score 6):

Here's an option that provides `\nonameappendix` and `\newappendix`. The first command sets up the chapter heading macros (removing the inclusion of a name in the chapter title), effectively treating it like a `\chapter*`. The second command does `\chapter[]{}` for convenience.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{lipsum}% http://ctan.org/pkg/lipsum
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\nonameappendix}{%
\def\@makechapterhead##1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
      \if@mainmatter
        \huge\bfseries \@chapapp\space \thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        %\vskip 20\p@ % <--- Removed
      \fi
    \fi
    %\interlinepenalty\@M % <--- Removed
    %\Huge \bfseries ##1\par\nobreak % <--- Removed
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}%
\def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter%
          \fi
        \fi
        }}{}}}
\makeatother
\newcommand{\newappendix}{\chapter[]{}}%
\usepackage[titletoc,toc,page]{appendix}% http://ctan.org/pkg/appendix
\begin{document}

\setcounter{tocdepth}{2} 
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\tableofcontents

\chapter{First chapter}

\begin{appendices}
  \nonameappendix
  \newappendix
  \label{ap1}
  \lipsum[1]

  \newappendix
  \lipsum[2]
\end{appendices}

\end{document}​
```

There's also the requirement modification to `\chaptermark` which typically sets `APPENDIX <num>.\ TITLE` in the header. It now just sets `APPENDIX <num>`. This is also modified by `\nonameappendix`, with definitions taken from [`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls).

Comment: For consistency with standard chapter titles, I think `\Huge` would be a better size of the title.

Comment: @CaramdirI thank you very much for your efforts. I applied your answer but unfortunately I'd forgotten the document is in spanish. Please see the **EDIT** section where I've added more info.

Comment: @Gaba_p: That's not me, that's Werner, who gave the answer.